# Pandas Dataframe plot not showing dates when matplotlib.dates used

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, date, matplotlib

I have the following code that plots COVID-19 confirmed cases country-wise against some dates.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates



df = pd.DataFrame({'Countries': ['Australia', 'India', 'UAE',  'UK'],
                   '3/1/20':    [   27,        3,   21,    36],
                   '3/2/20':    [   30,        5,   21,    40],
                   '3/3/20':    [   39,        5,   27,    51],
                   '3/4/20':    [   52,        28,   27,    86],
                   },
                   index = [0, 1, 2, 3])

print('Datframe:\n')
print(df)

dft=df.T
print('\n Transposed data:\n')
print(dft)

print(dft.columns)
dft.columns=dft.iloc[0]
dft=dft[1:]
print('\n Final data:\n')
print(dft)


dft.plot.bar(align='center')

# Set date ticks with 2-day interval
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=2))

# Change date format
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%Y'))

''' Note: If I comment above two lines, I get back x-axis ticks. '''

# Autoformatting dates ticks
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.title('COVID-19 confirmed cases')

plt.show()
```

Here I intended to show the dates on the x-axis ticks with 2-day intervals and get the dates formatted in a different style. However, in the plot, I don't get any ticks and labels on the x-axis as shown in the figure below.

[image]

However, when I comment out the instructions with `matplotlib.dates`, I get back the x-ticks and labels.

Can this be explained and fixed in a simple way? Also, can we get the same result using `fig, ax = plt.subplots()`?

Comment: See my answer, is it what you needed? Happy to help further.

Comment: Replied below the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. All you need to do is to restructure your dataframe. index the date. One way to do this is as follows;

Data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Countries': ['Australia', 'India', 'UAE',  'UK'],
                   '3/1/20':    [   27,        3,   21,    36],
                   '3/2/20':    [   30,        5,   21,    40],
                   '3/3/20':    [   39,        5,   27,    51],
                   '3/4/20':    [   52,        28,   27,    86],
                   },
                   index = [0, 1, 2, 3])
df2=df.set_index('Countries').T.unstack().reset_index()
df2#.plot(kind='bar')
df2.columns=['Countries','Date','Count']
df2['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])
df2.dtypes
```

Coarce date to datetime

```
df2.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
```

Groupby date, countries and unstack before plotting

```
df2.groupby([df2.index.date,df2['Countries']])['Count'].sum().unstack().plot.bar()
```

Outcome

[image]

Comment: But I wanted to use the `mdates` module. This doesn't get the two-day interval ticks too.

Comment: With mdates, I am only able to plot a line graph.                                                        
 loc = DayLocator(bymonthday=1, interval=2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%m-%d'))
#ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%b%d'))

df2.groupby([df2.index.date,df2['Countries']])['Count'].sum().unstack().plot(ax=ax)        It fails on me when I try a bar graph. df2.groupby([df2.index.date,df2['Countries']])['Count'].sum().unstack().plot.bar(ax=ax)

Comment: Thanks. I tried `df3=df2.groupby([df2.index.date,df2['Countries']])['Count'].sum().unstack()
ax.bar(df3.index, df3.columns)` and that retains the format. However, the plots sit on top of each other and I don't get distinct colors and positions. Let me know if you find out a clever trick.